# SSH port-forwarding logging me into remote server rather than actually opening Port

Tags: ssh, php, mysql, port-forwarding, xampp

Preface: I posted this to StackOverflow and they said I should post here instead. I followed one suggestion from the other post I made about using '' inside the powershell command and that stopped the program from hanging, but I now get a connection was actively refused message when doing `mysqli_connect()`. Below is the original post I made. Thank you for your time.

I'm trying to establish a ssh tunnel into a remote Linux server using a windows machine. I've checked the Linux server sshd_config and have confirmed that `AllowTcpForwarding` is `yes`. `GatewayPorts` is `no`, but my understanding is I should still be able to do local port forwarding using a cmd line like this.

```
ssh -L 3307:localhost:3306 myusername@myhostdomain
```

When I run this command all that happens is that I just ssh into the remote machine and from what I can tell from sites that test open ports I'm not actually opening any port. I should note that I only have ssh-client installed on my windows machine and due to some IT settings I haven't been able to install ssh-server to my local machine. If I need ssh-server installed to do port forwarding I would suppose this is my issue, but I'm new to this kind of setup and documentation on ssh is pretty clear that I'm doing this the correct way I think.

I've tried installing `SSH-Server` but can't use `Add-Services` on my computer to install server, not sure if this is required.

On the Linux server I've checked the `sshd_config`. I'm reticent to alter the security settings since I'm new to the server administration and still learning in this regard. Also my colleague urged me to be careful since the server contains a great deal of client data.

I'm trying to tunnel via cmd line and also via PHP `shell_exec()` using XAMPP.

```
shell_exec("powershell ssh -f -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 username@hostdomain -p 2200 sleep 5 >> logfile");
```

I would expect that that once the port is open in PHP I should be able to connect to the MySQL database using `mysqli_connect()`. Right now the ssh tunnel causes the locally hosted version of the site I'm working on to hang. No real error is thrown when I try the port forwarding, it just logs me in or with the `-N` option freezes the powershell command line.

Comment: `ssh -L 3307:localhost:3306 myusername@myhostdomain` will open a shell session to the remote system, but it should _also_ create a port forward from the local system port 3307 to the remote system port 3306. Which system is actually running the mysql server that you want to connect to? The local system or the remote system?

Comment: The Remote system has the MySQL database I'm trying to access. Does closing the shell session close the port-forwarding as well? If so can't I run the shell in the background using `-N`

Comment: Yes, the port is only forwarded while ssh is running.

Comment: Kenster, thanks for your help. It was an issue with the firewall that was preventing my access to the server. Thank you for your help. I'm new to this development flow and using ssh-tunneling like this. I now have access to the database as I intended.